# Capacitor / IOS safari: problem on canvas first rendering

Tags: ios, angular, safari, capacitor

I'm developping an App on IOS/Android using capacitor and having trouble displaying canvas or images with IOS/safari, but only on the first rendering.
After taking/importing a photo with the iphone/ipad and display it on the app, the first render is not right. The height on the img or canvas tag in the inspector is totally right, but the img is not filling totally the container making others elements to overflow above the image.

The thing is: at the moment where i touch the screen, or just scroll a centimer, everything becomes fine.  So it seems that it is only a bug on IOS on height calculation on the first rendering but i cannot figure out how to solve that properly.

I solved this by using setTimeout(...,0) when i receive the data of the image, which solves the problem but that is not satisfiying.
Is there any explanation of why is that happening ?